# ARM UEFI C StdLib BDS

Tags: arm, std, uefi

As I understand, If I build an UEFI application with the StdLib Pkg, it has a dependency to the ShellPKg and the application must be started through the new Shell (UEFI Interactive Shell v2.1 EDK II UEFI v2.60). So starting the application manually through the 2.1 Shell built with ShellPkg works, but not with the EBL shell, or through the gBS->StartImage.

To my question: is it possible to start an UEFI application that is using a Library built with StdLib through the BDS (boot device selection), without starting an Shell first and use startup.nsh to startup the UEFI application that you want?

For example trying to bootup the UEFI application with StdLib, with the following command in BDS won't work as its not started through Shell:
    Status = gBS->StartImage(ImageHandle, NULL, NULL);

So what I would like to achieve is a function call to execute a UEFI application with StdLib package during the boot in BDS. Most preferable not through startup scripts.

BR
Gigu

Comment: Why do you need StdLib? Can you not remove the dependency to StdLib?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can execute UEFI application through BDS.

To launch/execute UEFI application through BDS we need to use BOOT#### NV variable to launch/execute UEFI application.

To load UEFI driver through BDS we can use DRIVER#### NV variable to load DXE, UEFI drivers.

Using this way we don't need to use Starup.nsh way or Shell environment to launch/execute UEFI application.